# How to find the oxidation number of Co and Cr in [Co(NH3)6] [Cr(C2O4)3]?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

In the question I actually got I had to name the above compound, and I know how to name it but I don't know how to find the oxidation number of the above compound(which has to be mentioned in the IUPAC name). I actually know how to find the oxidation number in complexes but here both the ions are complex ions which makes it confusing. If someone needs the name its Hexaamminecobalt(?) trioxalatochromate(?)

Comment: So, what you propose to be the name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\ce{Co}$ is known to have two possible oxidation numbers in solution : +II and +III. Both make complexes with 6 $\ce{NH3}$. If $\ce{Co}$ is at +II, the charge of the complex is $2$+, as $\ce{NH3}$ is not charged.
If $\ce{Co}$ is at +III, the charge of the complex is $3$+ for the same reason.

For chromium, it is similar, as $\ce{Cr}$ may have oxidation number +II and +III. But the ligand oxalate is charged $-2$. The complex of $\ce{Cr}$ with three oxalate ions must compensate the charges of the cobalt complex (+$2$ or +$3$). So the charge of the chromium complex has to be -$2$ or -$3$. In other words, the complex ion is either $\ce{[Cr(C2O4)3]^{2-}}$ or $\ce{[Cr(C2O4)3]^{3-}}$. Let's compare the two possibilities, and the oxidation numbers of $\ce{Cr}$ in these two structures.

To get a complex $\ce{[Cr(C2O4)3]^{2-}}$, $\ce{Cr}$ oxidation number should be equal to $x$, with $x + 3(-2) = -2$. So $x$ = $+4$ or +IV. And unfortunately, this oxidation number IV does not exist for $\ce{Cr}$ in solution. This structure has to be abandoned,

On the other hand, to get a complex $\ce{[Cr(C2O4)3]^{3−}, Cr}$ must have an the oxidation number $y$ given by : $y +3(-2) = +3$. So $y$ = $+3$ = +III, and this is possible and even welcome. It corresponds to one of the requirements developed previously. As a final result, the complex ion $\ce{[Cr(C2O4)3]^{3-}}$ has a charge $3-$ that can be coupled with $\ce{Co(NH3)6^{3+}}$.

As a consequence, both Co and Cr are at oxidation number +III in the original structure $\ce{[Co(NH3)6][Cr(C2O4)3]}$

Comment: You could just say the charge of the ligands adds up to negative six, so the cations have to have a total of six charges as well.